# How to implement lazy loading on Horizontal scroll Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to implement a lazy load on horizontal scroll. Have gone through plugins of jquery but every one are providing on vertical scroll.

Initially need to show 4 items once i do horizontal scroll, need to load 4 more items.

have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

[Demo URL](http://jsfiddle.net/gAMyR/26/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAMyR/113/), I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').scroll(function(event) {
        if (this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth - this.scrollLeft < 50) {
            $(this).append('<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li>')
        }
    });
});
```